Why is socket.connected always false when I console log it?
My React application uses Socekt.io
Here is the Socket Context


import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const SocketContext = createContext();
const SocketProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState({});

  const createSocket = (position) => {
    if (!position) throw new Error("position is required to create connection");
    if (!["leader", "join"].includes(position)) throw new Error("The only positions allowed are leader and join");

    setSocket(
      io(import.meta.env["VITE_SERVER_URL"], {
        autoConnect: true,
        query: {
          position,
        },
      })
    );
  };

  return <SocketContext.Provider value={{ socket, createSocket }}>{children}</SocketContext.Provider>;
};

SocketProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export { SocketContext, SocketProvider };



Here is the page that runs the code to dynamically create the socket


import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { joinScripts, waitingScripts } from "../data/LoadingScripts";
import { LoadingSlides } from "../components/page-components/LoadingSlides";
import { RoomContext } from "../contexts/RoomContext";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
// socket
// import { createSocket } from "../logic/socket-conn";
import { SocketContext } from "../contexts/SocketContext";
import { DeepValidateRoom } from "../logic/DeepValidate";

export const LoadingRoom = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [receivedNewVotingBatch, setReceivedNewVotingBatch] = useState(false);
  const { socket, createSocket } = useContext(SocketContext);
  const { room, setRoom } = useContext(RoomContext);

  const loadingScripts = location?.state?.leader ? joinScripts : waitingScripts;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("socket", socket);
    console.log(Object.hasOwn(socket, "connected"));
    console.log(socket.connected);
    if (Object.keys(socket).length > 0) {
      // LEADER EVENTS
      if (location?.state?.leader) {
        socket.on("newId", (newRoom) => {
          setRoom((old) => ({ ...old, roomNumber: newRoom, currentParty: 1 }));
          socket.emit("setRoomData", { ...room, roomNumber: newRoom });
        });
      }

      // CLIENT EVENTS
      if (location?.state?.join) {
        socket.emit("joinRoom", room.roomNumber);
      }

      // LEADER AND CLIENT EVENTS
      if (location?.state?.votingMember || location?.state?.join || location?.state?.leader) {
        socket.on("restaurantDataReceive", (restaurantData, votingPower) => {
          setRoom((old) => ({ ...old, restaurantData, votingPower }));
          setReceivedNewVotingBatch(true);
        });
        socket.on("updatePartySize", (newPartySize) => {
          setRoom((old) => ({ ...old, currentParty: newPartySize }));
        });
      }
    } else {
      createSocket(location?.state?.leader ? "leader" : "join");
    }

    return () => {
      // this prevents adding multiple listeners upon re-render
      if (Object.keys(socket).length > 0) {
        socket.off("requestVotingRoundData");
        socket.off("newId");
        socket.off("restaurantDataReceive");
        socket.off("updatePartySize");
      }
    };
  }, [socket]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const hasRoomError = DeepValidateRoom(room, { checkData: true, checkRoomNumber: true }).error;
    // can't access page by url or if room is corrupted
    if (!location.state) navigate("..");

    if (room.partySize == room.currentParty && !hasRoomError && receivedNewVotingBatch) {
      navigate("../voting");
    }

    if (room.restaurantData.length == 1 && !hasRoomError && receivedNewVotingBatch) {
      navigate("../winner");
    }
  }, [room]);

  return <LoadingSlides data={loadingScripts} />;
};



The console statements look like this

I need a guard clause to not run all the socket statements in the useEffect until the socket is actually created. Any help or guidance in how I should correctly set this up is greatly appreciated.
